# Define Matlab Scatter Plot scale

Tags: matlab, scale, axis, scatter

I have the following scatter graph: [image: http://i.imgur.com/j5Yca86.png]

As you can see by the figure, I've defined a graph where each size of the grid is 5. I guess the grid follows the interval of the axis itself but I haven't quite figured out how change that (for example with a size 1), any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid spacing is determined by the tick marks on the axes. Set the properties `'XTick'` and `'YTick'` of the axes to control the spacing of the grid, as follows:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [50:75])
set(gca, 'YTick', [52:2:75])
```